# How permanently turn off airplane mode Windows 8, 8.1 operating system

Tags: wireless-networking

We have just come across this potential headache with Windows 8, 8.1, and students.

On our laptops students have the ability to turn flightmode on and off from the charms menu. This disconnects all Wi-Fi and hides available networks.

Searching using the usual places only seems to give us replies of how you enable/disable the option, but having the option removed altogether would be ideal, but without removing the whole charms menu.

Has anyone here in education come up with a solution or workaround for this at all?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use Group Policy settings or Registry to disable student account use of Airplane Mode.
You might find the settings at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx

This question has been asked in the Microsoft forum: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c9544732-bc3d-4afd-a98d-e4d45a7c8afd/disable-airplane-mode-remove-the-ability-to-turn-it-on-and-off?forum=w8itprogeneral
and in edugeek: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-8/114018-windows-8-airplane-mode-flightmode-setting-remove-option.html

The best answer in the link above is"
"Although I do not consider this overly substancial contribution, I have (kind of) narrowed down what is being turned on/off with the Airplane mode. The bad news is (and why it is only kind of narrowed down) is that it is unique to each PC/Wireless card/Install

There are references to a radioEnable DWORD in the registry that is at 1 when wireless is enabled and 0 when it is disabled, in my case these were in the following locations

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Cl ass{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002]

Now just to see if there is a quick way to enumerate the registry on a schedule (including on startup and shutdown) and change all radioEnable DWORDS to 1 if in the 0 state"

Comment: I checked into Microsoft group policy reference to see if there's a setting for this - there isn't. in my case student laptop radio value is 0 but wireless is connected. so can you clarify the actual dword where??

Comment: The user cited above shows the location of the item in the *Windows Registry*. If you find this location works on the lab PC's, you would need to export that key and value from the Registry, then apply that as a REG file to each PC. Group policy would be a better way to do it, but I have not yet found such a setting.

Comment: but i did not find any radioEnable DWORDS. so we need to create  DWORDS named "radioEnable"

Comment: after searching m found out these

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002\Ndi\params\Radio\enum]
"1"="Disable"
"0"="Enable"

so tell in this case if i need to put additional value ???

Comment: Yes, create the key and the value, if you are familiar with the Registry. If it works on a test PC, export the new reg key and run it as a script on the lab machines.